# Browser Compatibility for WebTransport

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, safari, webtransport

I'm exploring the potential of WebTransport for my web application, but I'm concerned about its current browser support. Can someone provide an overview of which browsers support WebTransport, their levels of implementation, and any known compatibility issues? Are there any polyfills or fallback strategies available for browsers that don't yet support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebTransport holds good compatibility for Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Opera. You can also find differences when it comes to some experimental parameters. Just take a look at [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebTransport#browser_compatibility).

As to polyfills, a polyfill (or rather ponyfill that provides functionality as a standalone module you can use) called `webtransport-ponyfill-websocket` that implements some of the features of WebTransport is available. For more information, you can refer to [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/capabilities/web-apis/webtransport#polyfill).

Comment: thanks for sharing the above. seems like except for Safari all major browsers support WebTransport. even for safari, work is in progress to support WebTransport.